# Insert and Update on one click

Tags: php, html, database

I have two table Billing_month and registration in mysql. i want to insert into Billing_month and at the same time i want to update a row (Arrears) in registration table. how can i do this.

PHP Code is:

```
<?php
    //create connection
    include("database/db.php");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } 


    // Insert Data

    @$month=$_POST['Bill_month'];
    @$issuedate=$_POST['Bill_issue_date'];
    @$duedate=$_POST['Bill_due_date'];
    @$surcharge =$_POST['Surcharge'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO billing_month (Bill_month,Bill_issue_date,Bill_due_date,Surcharge) values('$month','$issuedate','$duedate','$surcharge')";

   if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
       echo "Records added successfully.";
   } else{
       echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }

   // close connection
   mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Need your help?

Comment: Google `multi_query` or otherwise you can just create two single queries and execute them one after the other.

Comment: Already done. but did'nt work..

Comment: the multi query or the two single ones??

Comment: both are not working

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I suggest that they  are inside a transaction to ensure database consistency.

Comment: Just a tiny headsup. It would be wise to sanitize your input. Even better, go for a prepered statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would only run the query update if the insert was successful.

```
<?php
//create connection
include("database/db.php");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Insert Data
@$month=$_POST['Bill_month'];
@$issuedate=$_POST['Bill_issue_date'];
@$duedate=$_POST['Bill_due_date'];
@$surcharge =$_POST['Surcharge'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO billing_month (Bill_month,Bill_issue_date,Bill_due_date,Surcharge) 
values('$month','$issuedate','$duedate','$surcharge')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  $res = "Records added successfully.";

  // Update Registration Arrears query
  $sql_upadte = "Update registration ...."
  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql_update)){
    $res .= "<br>Registration record updated successfully.";
  }else{
    $res .= "<br>ERROR: Could not able to execute.<br>".$sql_update."<br>".mysqli_error($link);
  }

  echo($res);

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: I do recommend you sanitize and validate the $_POST[] data before running your insert query. Also, you should bind your params.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple multi query, you can look at [php - multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) here.

```
<?php

$query = "INSERT INTO billing (...) VALUES (....) ; ";
$query .= "UPDATE billing SET .... ; ";

if(!mysqli_multi_query($link,$query)){
  ...
}
```

Otherwise you can still do just do two single queries and execute them one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries to insert and to update, then execute them

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO billing_month (Bill_month,Bill_issue_date,Bill_due_date,Surcharge) 
            values('$month','$issuedate','$duedate','$surcharge')";

$sqlUpdate = "Place your update query here";

$insert = mysqli_query($sql);
$update = mysqli_query($sqlUpdate);
```

Comment: now the error is:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp\www\login\Billing_month_code.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

After insert into your billing table get last inserted id

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Then update your registration table.

```
$query = "UPDATE registration SET .... WHERE billing_id = $id; ";
mysql_query($query);
```